# How to change pem file for an ec2-instance without creating new ec2-instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an instance and its pem file named as `demo.pem`,
 But due to some security i have to change my old `demo.pem` file with `demos.pem` for the same instance.
**I do not want to create new instance for changing pem file** => Is it possible? | Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth understanding how keypairs work...

When logging into Linux using keypairs, you specify a username and a keypair, eg:

```
ssh -i demo.pem ec2-user@54.11.22.33
```

Linux then looks in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file belonging to that user, eg:

```
/home/users/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If looks for the public key in that file that matches the private key used for login. It then does keypair magical stuff and determines whether to allow the person to login.

Therefore, **to enable login on an instance using a new keypair**:

- Add the public half of the keypair to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in the appropriate user's home directory
- If desired, remove an old key from that file to remove access permissions

You can have multiple keys in that file, which permit login via any of the authorized keypairs.

Comment: Good explanation, but I'd add one thing: _Do not log out of the window that you used to edit `authorized_keys` until you have verified you're able to log in with the new key._ Accidentally changing the permissions on the file, or adding an incorrect key, would otherwise leave you locked out of the account.

Comment: Ha! It sounds like you are speaking from experience!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , i do't understand this line => Add the private half of the keypair to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file in the appropriate user's home directory

Comment: I logged in with ssh and currently i am in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, Now what do i need to add here? i have new keypair now what is private half of the keypair?

Comment: What @JohnRotenstein means is public key generated from your new private key.   as `it looks for the public key in that file`.  Append it the file with new public key and test the login first before you log out.   ALWAYS create a snapshot before making any changes, it is easier to roll back the mistake than going through all the trouble to mount the drive or whatever.

Comment: Oops! Fixed my answer. Yes, the **public key** goes in the `authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer from A to Z:

1. create a pem key pair in the aws interface at (example)
   https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#KeyPairs:
2. then go to your download files and modify access mode

```
chmod 400 yourNewPemName.pem
```

3. then generate the public key:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f yourNewPemName.pem > yourNewPemName.pub
```

4. connect to the ec2 instance:

```
cd ~ / .ssh
```

5. then replace the contents of the `authorized_keys` file, with the contents of your public key contents generated above step 3